# Replication Monitor: Cannot Connect to Publisher

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication

Everything It was working fine for a quite long time period, but suddenly this evening I found that I the replication does not work and I cannot browse the publications in the Replication Monitor

Please have a look at the attached image.
[image]

The publisher at the bottom is OK - attached and working. But the publisher at the top is attached, but for some reason I cannot browse its Publications. When Selecting something the left side is white. As you can see there is a red "x" which means that there is a problem with the connection.

I tried to remove and then to re-add the publisher, but this does not solve the problem.

In Windows Event Logger I found this Error:
"The transaction log for database 'Distribution' is full due to 'LOG_BACKUP'. " And I'm not quite sure what is this....

Any ideas are welcome
Regards,

Comment: Have you check any logs? Windows Application logs or SQL logs?

Comment: Yes And I found this error
The transaction log for database 'Distribution' is full due to 'LOG_BACKUP'.

Comment: Then you need to backup and truncate the log. Which that should be getting done daily anyways.

Comment: Yes this was the problem, I just had to do it on the Distribution Database

Answer (score 1):

This was the problem:

In Windows Event Logger I found this Error: "The transaction log for database 'Distribution' is full due to 'LOG_BACKUP'. " And I'm not quite sure what is this....

Once I truncated the log for Database Distribution everything was OK

Comment: Where to exactly need to navigate in Windows Event logger, what event Id here we are looking for?